# Handling errors conditionally in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I started using react-query a couple of days ago and everything seems amazing but I don't understand how I can handle errors returned from the server with their status code and error key

lets take the peace of code below as an example

```
const onError = (error) => {
    console.log('error occurred', error)
}
let { id } = useParams()
const { data: User, isLoading, isError, error, isRefetching, status, refetch } = useQuery(['get-user-by-id', id], getUserById(id), {
    onError
})
```

in this scenario when the API returns an error the onError function does not fire furthermore when i try to render a toast containing the {error} the message is Missing queryFn and when rendering {error?.message} the message is just `Error`

i would like to be able to get the message sent from the server with its key, ex.

```
if(error?.response.status === 404){
    if(error?.response?.data?.detail){
       let error = error?.response?.data?.detail
    }else if(error?.response?.data?.message){  //another error key that might return 
            let error = error?.response?.data?.message
    }// and so on...
    
}else if (error?.response?.status === 400){} // and so on...
```

or a key that I know my API would return depending on the status code this is especially critical for forms, while a get request could be fine with simple non-detailed error messages, a post request might hold relevant information about the error that can help the user understand it like if a name for a certain field is already taken or their is complex validation involved in the serverside, how can i handle error's in the way i explained above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, according to your code, that you are not passing a function as the query function parameter, but you are *executing* the function during render:

```
useQuery(['get-user-by-id', id], getUserById(id),
```

unless this was a typo, what you need is:

```
useQuery(['get-user-by-id', id], () => getUserById(id),
```

but given that you said you get `Missing queryFn` as error, I'm pretty sure this is it.